# PostgreSQL, config table constraint

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have table represents config for some companies:

```
id 
config_id
company_id
```

Record in table means that config with number for instance 1 enabled for company for instance number 1. If company_id is null - that means given config enabled for all companies.

I need to create constraint(s) for given config_id there can be only one record with company_id = null, or multiple, but unique company_id which is not null.

Something like that does not fix up the problem:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX config_unique_all_companies 
                       ON company_config_relations (config_id) 
                       WHERE company_id IS NULL

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX config_company_unique 
                       ON company_config_relations (config_id, company_id) 
                       WHERE company_id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX config_unique_idx 
    ON company_config_relations (config_id, company_id)
    WHERE config_id IS NOT NULL AND company_id IS NOT NULL;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX config_unique_companies_idx
    ON company_config_relations (company_id) 
    WHERE config_id IS NULL;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX config_unique_default_config_idx
    ON company_config_relations (COALESCE(config_id, 0)) 
    WHERE company_id IS NULL AND config_id IS NULL;
```

The last one is the most interesting one. It creates an index containing just one element with a constant value. `COALESCE(config_id, 0)` is always `0`. It is a trick to create a constant index value, because `... ON company_config_relations (0) ...` will not work.